# Getting all values into single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like the following

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 ) )
```

Now I want only values of this two dimensional array

The result should be `array(5,6,7)`

Comment: Try `array_merge_recursive`. I have never used or tested this function, so I am just jotting this down as a comment.

Comment: @erisco I just tried it, and it doesn't appear to flatten it.

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a hack/neat trick depending on how you look at it ;)

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a);
```

Comment: You do not lack today, sir. This effectively serves as a foldl1 from functional programming, which inherently is a beautiful solution. If I could donate more rep for this answer, I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach($parentArray as $pa)
{
  if(is_array($pa))
     $result= array_merge($result, $pa);
  else
     $result[] = $pa;

}
```

Use `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `array_values()` which returns an array of all array values, sans-keys.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

**Update:**

Alternatively for an already multi-dimensional array, you can use the following recursive function (borrowed from http://davidwalsh.name/flatten-nested-arrays-php):

```
function array_flatten($array,$return)
{
  for($x = 0; $x <= count($array); $x++)
  {
    if(is_array($array[$x]))
    {
      $return = array_flatten($array[$x],$return);
    }
    else
    {
      if($array[$x])
      {
        $return[] = $array[$x];
      }
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
array_merge($a[0], $a[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function flattenArray($array) {
   $flattened = array();
   foreach($array as $value) {
       if (is_array($value)) {
           $flattened = array_merge($flattened, flattenArray($value));
       } else {
           $flattened[] = $value;
       }
   }
   return $flattened;
}

$array = array(1, array(2, 3), array(4, array(5, 6)));
var_dump($array, flattenArray($array));
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(5)
      [1]=>
      int(6)
    }
  }
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(6)
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/IWtILiBD).